# Oracle Restoring Database on Existing Database or rename database

Tags: oracle, restore

I want to change my DB name in Oracle. I am using this command:

```
nid TARGET=SYS/welc0me12$@CSPROD DBNAME=CSGOLD SETNAME=Y
```

After that I am getting an error:

```
Datafile E:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\CSPROD\SYSTEM02.DB - wrote new name
ID-00111: Oracle error reported from target database while executing
   begin       dbms_backup_restore.nidprocessdf(:fno, :istemp, :skipped, :idchg
d,                                        :nmchged);    end;
RA-20000: File E:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\CSPROD\TEMP01.DBF has wrong dbid or
dbname, remove or restore the offending file.
RA-06512: at "SYS.X$DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE", line 6848
RA-06512: at line 1
hange of database name failed.
ust finish change or REVERT changes before attempting any database operation.
BNEWID - Completed with errors.
```

Comment: I see nothing in the documentation of nid to suggest that it will work properly over a tns connection.  I do see in the docs that the database MUST be started in MOUNT status - not OPEN., which would further suggest that this is not something you can do over a tns connection.

Comment: @EdStevens Operations such as `DUPLICATE DATABASE` work over a TNS connection. Active duplication in fact requires one. NID over a TNS connection works according to MOS (e.g: How to Change the DBID and the DBNAME by using NID (Doc ID 224266.1))

Comment: @BalazsPapp - you are correct.  I use rman DUPLICATE all the time ... I just failed to connect those dots. I should have paid more attention to the details of the posted error.

Answer (score 0):

Tempfiles can be dropped then recreated without any hassle.

I would just try dropping the tempfile and then run nid again:

```
alter database tempfile 'E:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\CSPROD\TEMP01.DBF' drop;
shutdown immediate
startup mount
exit

nid TARGET=SYS/welc0me12$@CSPROD DBNAME=CSGOLD SETNAME=Y
```

Comment: Failed NID is a conundrum. You cannot open the database, because that would be attempting a database operation, and you must finish or revert the change first. And tempfiles can NOT be dropped unless the database is open.

Comment: @Quigi Tempfiles CAN be dropped in mount stage.

Answer (score 0):

Changing DBNAME is a very serious procedure and you may have to recur to your backup, which could lead to downtime at the least. So, at this point:

```
Change of database name failed.
Must finish change or REVERT changes before attempting any database operation.
DBNEWID - Completed with errors.
```

Don't try to open the Database, don't shut it down, and respect the message thay says:

```
Must finish change or REVERT changes before attempting any database operation.
```

This could cost you.

In my case, I had missed the clause `SET NEWNAME FOR TEMPFILE 3 TO '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mvtest/datafiles/tmp01.dbf';` while doing `restore database;` and was missing the tempfile after restoring the backup. Then when I tried to change DBNAME with `nid` and this happened. I tried to open the Database anyway and had to recur to the backup, terrible decision. In my case it was a non production database but it still was a bummer because it required many hours of processing. The solution is to drop de tempfile then rerun nid.

Open a sqlplus session and find out the tempfile's name and then drop it. You will just recreate it later on, no problem:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
select name from v$tempfile;
alter database tempfile '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mvtest/datafiles/tmp01.dbf' drop including datafiles;
```

And then rerun nid and you will be safe:

`nid TARGET='/ as sysdba' dbname=mvtest SETNAME=YES`

This did it for me later on, when I retried it just to document it and save someone's life.